Fiber doesn't parse JSON payload properly
I'm implementing a POST request, which accepts JSON payload like this:
{
    "channelCode": "6014",
    "trxDateTime": "2022-12-30T14:52:04+07:00",
    "partnerServiceId": "    8099",
    "customerNo": "080012345123",
    "virtualAccountNo": "8099080012345123",
    "virtualAccountName": "Clive Morton",
    "referenceNo": "221230BI02639274",
    "paymentRequestId": "221230BI02639274",
    "hashedSourceAccountNo": "8a9c1fc0a64a5f77555b9cef1a3dac08",
    "paidAmount": {
        "value": "210",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "totalAmount": {
        "value": "205",
        "currency": "USD"
    }
}

This is my model:
type VAPaymentRequest struct {
    Id                    string    `json:"id" db:"id"`
    CreatedAt             time.Time `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"`
    ChannelCode           string    `json:"channelCode" db:"channel_code"`
    TrxDateTime           time.Time `json:"trxDateTime" db:"trx_date"`
    PartnerServiceId      string    `json:"partnerServiceId" db:"partner_service_id"`
    CustomerNo            string    `json:"customerNo" db:"customer_no"`
    VirtualAccountNo      string    `json:"virtualAccountNo" db:"virtual_account_no"`
    VirtualAccountName    string    `json:"virtualAccountName" db:"virtual_account_name"`
    ReferenceNo           string    `json:"referenceNo" db:"reference_no"`
    PaymentRequestId      string    `json:"paymentRequestId" db:"payment_request_id"`
    HashedSourceAccountNo string    `json:"hashedSourceAccountNo" db:"hashed_source_account_not"`

    PaidAmount struct {
        Value    string `json:"paidAmountValue" db:"paid_amount_value"`
        Currency string `json:"paidAmountCurrency" db:"paid_amount_currency"`
    } `json:"paidAmount"`

    TotalAmount struct {
        Value    string `json:"totalAmountValue" db:"total_amount_value"`
        Currency string `json:"totalAmountCurrency" db:"total_amount_currency"`
    } `json:"totalAmount"`

}

And the code to handle the POST request:
func (qt *VAHandler) VAPayment(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    //ctx := c.Context()
    var body domain.VAPaymentRequest

    if err := c.BodyParser(&body); err != nil {
        qt.Logger.Error("VAPayment-ParseBody", zap.Any("error", err))
        return helper.Response(c, fiber.StatusBadRequest, "Bad Request", nil)
    }

    return helper.Response(c, fiber.StatusOK, "OK", body)
}

Running the code, the output is:
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "id": "",
    "created_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "channelCode": "6014",
    "trxDateTime": "2022-12-30T14:52:04+07:00",
    "partnerServiceId": "    8099",
    "customerNo": "080012345123",
    "virtualAccountNo": "8099080012345123",
    "virtualAccountName": "Clive Morton",
    "referenceNo": "221230BI02639274",
    "paymentRequestId": "221230BI02639274",
    "hashedSourceAccountNo": "8a9c1fc0a64a5f77555b9cef1a3dac08",
    "paidAmount": {
      "paidAmountValue": "",
      "paidAmountCurrency": ""
    },
    "totalAmount": {
      "totalAmountValue": "",
      "totalAmountCurrency": ""
    }
  },
  "message": "OK"
}

Everything is printed properly, except paidAmount and totalAmount. what's missing here?
I'm using Fiber 2.48, btw.

there is no paidAmountValue or totalAmoutValue in your input JSON. If even, it would be paidAmoutvalue because the value in your json is lowercase ... I don't know about the specifics of this bodyparser, but probably need something like json: "paidAmout.value" or maybe just json: "value" or similar to indicate the name of the nested property

@derpirscher yep silly me. The proper code should be: Value    stringjson:"value" db:"paid_amount_value"`. etc...
